# Python display plain text as html

Tags: python, flask, summernote

I gotta do a notes app so I decided to use `summernote` and `python flask` for this.
I got a form where the user has to input the title and the content using a summernote textarea then the input is stored in the DB.
The problem that I got is when I try to display the notes they come as plain text
[image]

this is how I display them

```
            {% for foo in notes %}
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="card-title">{{ foo.title }}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="ribbon-wrapper ribbon-lg">
                        <div class="ribbon bg-primary">
                            <p>{{ foo.category_name }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        {{ foo.content }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Is there any way that I could actually render the HTML content instead of displaying it as plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jinja's `safe` or `escape` filters

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/?highlight=safe#safe

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/?highlight=safe#escape

```
{{ foo.content | safe }}   
{{ foo.content | escape }}
```

Always be mindful of trusting user input: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/security/

Comment: Calling `| safe` filter will bypass the autoescape functionality! OP develops a note app, hence user provides the HTML string. Trusting this is a terrible idea, and a great opportunity for XSS attack. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/security/

Comment: @KristofGilicze that's true. Do you have an alternate solution? I would typically use CSP to protect against this.